# Json Array splitting issue Logstash configuration : Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array (start marker at [Source: (S

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

This is how my json object looks like, i have verified that the json i am getting is a valid. I tries setting up configuration files for the same, but always get the same error

SON parse error, original data now in message field {:error=>#, :data=>"{\"total_rows\":15587,\"offset\":0,\"rows\":[\r"}
[2019-08-05T21:07:49,799][WARN ][logstash.filters.split   ] Only String and Array types are splittable. field:[doc][serversGroups] is of type = NilClass
[2019-08-05T21:07:50,584][WARN ][logstash.filters.split   ] Only String and Array types are splittable. field:[doc][serversGroups][ActiveUsers] is of type = NilClass

This is my source Config file i am using for logstash

```
filter {

json {
source => "message"
skip_on_invalid_json => "true"
target => "doc"
}

split {

field => "[doc][serversGroups]"

}

split {

field => "[doc][serversGroups][ActiveUsers]"
}

date {
      match => [ "[doc][date]", "UNIX" ]
      target => "unix_time"
    }

mutate {
      convert => { "[doc][serversGroups][ActiveUsers][handle]" => "integer"
                   "[doc][serversGroups][list][UsedLicenses]" => "integer"
                   "[doc][serversGroups][list][issuedLicenses]" => "integer"
      }
    }

fingerprint {
concatenate_all_fields => "true"
method => "SHA256"
target => "fingerprint"
  }
}

output {

stdout {
codec => "rubydebug"
}

elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "pyyython"
codec => "json"
document_id => "%{[fingerprint]}"
}


}
```

This is my source JSON

```
{
  "total_rows": 156122,
  "offset": 12,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "key": "12345",
      "value": {
        "rev": "1-12345"
      },
      "doc": {
        "_id": "12345",
        "_rev": "1-12345",
        "date": "15645348122",
        "HostServerName": "abc.com",
        "serversGroups": [
          {
            "ServiceName": "--- ",
            "list": {
              "issuedLicenses": "123",
              "UsedLicenses": "12"
            },
            "ActiveUsers": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "ServiceName": "--- ",
            "list": {
              "issuedLicenses": "123",
              "UsedLicenses": "12"
            },
            "ActiveUsers": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "ServiceName": "--- ",
            "list": {
              "issuedLicenses": "123",
              "UsedLicenses": "12"
            },
            "ActiveUsers": [
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            "ServiceName": "--- ",
            "list": {
              "issuedLicenses": "123",
              "UsedLicenses": "1"
            },
            "ActiveUsers": [
              {
                "user": "me",
                "user_host": "myself",
                "dispay": "andI",
                "version": "v1.1",
                "server_host": "testing.abc.com",
                "handle": "12345",
                "last_date_license_check": "7/7",
                "last_time_license_check": "12:12"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
SON parse error, original data now in message field {:error=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array (start marker at [Source: (S"; line: 1, column: 39])87,"offset":0,"rows":[
"; line: 2, column: 41]>, :data=>"{\"total_rows\":15587,\"offset\":0,\"rows\":[\r"}
[2019-08-05T21:07:49,799][WARN ][logstash.filters.split   ] Only String and Array types are splittable. field:[doc][serversGroups] is of type = NilClass
[2019-08-05T21:07:50,584][WARN ][logstash.filters.split   ] Only String and Array types are splittable. field:[doc][serversGroups][ActiveUsers] is of type = NilClass
```

not sure if my splitting is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The source JSON that you show is clearly invalid, since it ends with a comma. If I replace the comma with

```
]
}
}
]
}
```

then it is valid. With that change made it can be split using

```
split { field => "[doc][rows][0][doc][serversGroups]" }
split { field => "[doc][rows][0][doc][serversGroups][ActiveUsers]" }
```

Comment: I have those closing braces, that is not the issue!

It is a 150+ mb file with this type of structuring !

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way i have formatted my configuration file ?

Comment: Only that you are trying to split fields that do not exist.

Comment: nope, this is exactly how my JSON file is, with more and more objects nested in arrays.

I cant split [rows][0] as i have over 15k objects in them and they dynamically increase !

Comment: If you need to split every member of an array you would have to write that in ruby.

Comment: could you provide me with an example of how it would look ?